# Changing Background Image with cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, background

I am looking for help in putting a cookie into this script so the browser remembers the background image selected when the browser is closed or changed page. Any help would be much appreciated!

```js
function changeTheme()
{

  var e = document.getElementById("themes");
  var theme = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  console.log(theme);
  document.getElementById("shelf").style.backgroundImage = "url("+theme+")";

}
```

```html
<body id="shelf">
<select id="themes" onChange="changeTheme()" name="ChangeBG">
  <option value="images/background1.jpg" selected="selected">Default</option>
  <option value="images/background2.jpg">Heart</option>
  <option value="images/background3.jpg">Earthly</option>
  <option value="images/background4.jpg">Sunflowers</option>
  <option value="images/background5.jpg">Mountin</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the only piece you are missing is the setting and getting of the cookie. Here is a post about [setting and getting cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery) using both jquery and javascript.

This is jquery but it gets the job done.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<!--download jquery.cookie from here http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="images/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var theme = $.cookie("backgroundImage");
    if (theme){document.getElementById("shelf").style.backgroundImage = "url("+theme+")";}
    $("#themes").change(function() {
        theme = $(this).val();
        $.cookie("backgroundImage", theme);
        document.getElementById("shelf").style.backgroundImage = "url("+theme+")";
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body id="shelf">
<!--<select id="themes" onChange="changeTheme()" name="ChangeBG">-->
<select id="themes" name="ChangeBG">
  <option value="images/background1.jpg" selected="selected">Default</option>
  <option value="images/background2.jpg">Heart</option>
  <option value="images/background3.jpg">Earthly</option>
  <option value="images/background4.jpg">Sunflowers</option>
  <option value="images/background5.jpg">Mountin</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This works great when the browser remains open, but when you close the browser the image changes back to default this is thee CSS i am using, is there a way to get the CSS Background image load from the Cookie?

Comment: body {
 margin: auto;
 background-color: #000000;
        background-image: url("images/background1.jpg");
 text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 color: #fff;
 min-width: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: 50% top;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
}

Comment: Yes thank you i did that, i have read that i need to add a persistent cookie until its time-to-live has elapsed not a session cookie, i cant see where i can set the time to expire length? So it does not reset once the browser has been shut down?

Comment: Also Also IE will only persist a cookie if it has an Expires date